# Calculation for filtered average Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

not even sure this is the right title to describe my problem..

I have some data about some companies and their workers, and how many hours they are absent from work. In the screenshot below you see I have the total amount of absence hours per year per company, and another column with total number of workers of each company. 
[image: table]

I created a calculation to show the average number of absence hours per worker using this formula:

```
SUM[Hours]/COUNTD[WorkerID]
```

So for example in the first row I have 295098/786=375

I've put this worksheet in a Dashboard with filters, i.e. cause of absence.
Of course when selecting a specific cause of absence, i.e. sick leave, values in the worksheet change, say for example first row becomes 
56092 sickness hours / 638 workers who have been absent for sickness = 88 average hours per worker for sickness absence

My problem is, the average is changing (and that's ok because it's changing for each cause) but it is calculated ONLY on those workers that actually are absent for THAT cause.
My desired output is an extra column in which average is computed NOT only on those who are absent for that cause, but on the total workers of that company. something like:

```
SUM[Hours for that cause i.e.sickness]/COUNTD[total workersID of that company]
#and not
SUM[Hours for that cause i.e.sickness]/COUNTD[total workersID absent for sickness]
```

How can I obtain this?

Answer (score 0):

You may achieve this using **LOD (Level of Detail) expressions**.

Basically, if you want the calculation done with all data (The scope is your table) you may use below:

```
{COUNTD[total workersID of that company]}
```

If you want to fix the calculation to another detail then you should play around with `FIXED` keyword. A good place to start is:
[online help page from tableau.com](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/calculations_calculatedfields_lod_overview.html)

Comment: I will try this and let you know if it works, thank you!